# How can get record from sql database to char array or string or integer?

Tags: c++, sql

I am using sqlite and i can see records with sql queries but how can take this record to char array or string or integer variables in c++ ?

i used below code and it's working i can see records but how can save they in c++ variables ?

```
/* Create SQL statement */
sql = "SELECT names FROM kullanicilar WHERE specialNumber='2'";

/* Execute SQL statement */
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
```

like this i can see "name" but i don't know how do i keep at char array.

EDIT : i did with strange way :

```
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_stmt *res;
int rc;
char *sql;

char chrArray[20];

/* Open database */
rc = sqlite3_open("verilerimiz.db", &db);

if( rc )
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
  return(0);
}
else
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
}


sql = "SELECT names FROM kullanicilar WHERE specialNumber='2'";


rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &res, 0);
rc = sqlite3_step(res);

sprintf(chrArray, (const char*) sqlite3_column_text(res,0));


cout<<"and now i can keep query result at array -> chrArray[20]  = "<< chrArray <<endl;

sqlite3_close(db);
```

Comment: If you need to access the rows returned by a query, you should be using [prepared statements](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) directly, not `sqlite3_exec()`, which is only really good for things that don't return anything, like `INSERT`s.

Comment: i tried but i failed again. can you show me with a example.lets say i have "char chr[20];" and sprintf(chr, " what i need to write here");

Comment: `std::strcpy()` would be more appropriate, assuming the string returned by `sqlite3_column_text()` will fit in 20 chars... Or since you're using C++, putting it in a `std::string` so you don't have to worry about things like that

Comment: i did with sqlite3_prepare like you said but it is good way i don't know check my edit and thanks.

Comment: That's... Not how you use `sprintf()`.